# Is there a proper way to daisy-chaining the classes and called it the right way?

Tags: c#, class

I'm working on creating class hierarchy tree so they get organized and easier to read in Intellisense when typing the objects path.  Like "System.IO.FileStream()" for example.

I noticed it works when I used var but it doesn't work when I use the full classes naming.  Also I noticed it doesn't work when I use List<> object.  Can anyone explain to me why and what did I do wrong.  Thanks...

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Trim { get; set; }
}
public class Dealer
{
    public Vehicle VehicleData { get { return new Vehicle(); } set; }
}
```

This one works...

```
var vehicle = new Dealer().VehicleData;
vehicle.Year = "2007";
vehicle.Make = "Ford";
```

This one does not works...

```
Dealer().VehicleData vehicle = new Dealer().VehicleData;
vehicle.Year = "2004";
vehicle.Make = "Buick";
```

This one does not works either...

```
var vehicles = new List<Dealer().VehicleData>();
vehicles.Add(
    new Dealer().VehicleData {
        Year = "2001", 
        Make = "Toyota"
    }
);
vehicles.Add(
    new Dealer().VehicleData {
        Year = "2003", 
        Make = "Volvo"
    }
);
```

Comment: I think you may be looking for namespaces rather than a class hierarchy. Also, please never just say "this doesn't work" - always say what you expected to happen and **how** something "doesn't work".

Comment: This is a very bad Idea because you can never call the object again.. You will just create a new vehicle every time, not to mention a dealer with only 1 car isn't much of a dealer

Comment: The projects I have at work had gotten too big, so it need to be re-organzied as class hierarchy for asier navigating through the class heirarchy.  So, anyway, I'm guessing the last 2 examples that doesn't work is due to wrong programming concept and I'm seeking guidance on pointing the script in the right direction.

Comment: P.S. - Most of those classes will become protected or internal, so the class hierarchy naming will get instance class somehow.

Comment: Unfortunately, even though I've added an answer here, it is completely unclear what you're *really* asking, so I'm going to have to vote to close this.

Answer (score 7):

`Dealer().VehicleData` is not a type, it's a property.

You can't declare a variable to be of type *property*.

This makes just as little sense as this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

...
new Person().Name test;
```

Note that this line:

```
var vehicle = new Dealer().VehicleData;
```

actually means the same as *this* line:

```
Vehicle vehicle = new Dealer().VehicleData;
```

Also note that in this case you're not storing a reference to the dealer, only to the vehicle, so you should write the above code like this:

```
var vehicle = new Vehicle();
```

Are you actually looking for the concept of [namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973231.aspx)?

This:

```
System.IO.FileStream()
```

actually has to be used like this:

```
new System.IO.FileStream()
```

and the parts are as follows:

```
 +----------------------+---- calling the constructor of FileStream
 |                      |
v+v                     vv
new System.IO.FileStream()
    ^---+---^ ^----+---^
        |          |
        |          +-- the name of the class
        |
        +-- the namespace of the FileStream class
```

To declare it:

```
namespace System.IO
{
    public class FileStream
    {
        public FileStream()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

*(note that [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) actually doesn't have a parameterless constructor so the above is in fact wrong, but you get the gist)*

Comment: Namespace is an analogy I'm trying to use for classes hierarchy.  The problem with namespaces is I can't passed the argument variables into every classes down the hierarchy tree's branches.  Okay, I see you're saying I'm using property which is why it wouldn't work.  So what is my other options?

Comment: Namespaces. Unfortunately you have not described good enough what you want to do and why, so I cannot tell you anything more concrete than that.

Comment: Inner class is one way to call it what I don't know what it's called with what I'm using with daisy-chaining classes.  Oh well.  :-(  I guess I'll have to figure it out on my own.  Thanks for trying.

Comment: Though I still don't understand what you're trying to achieve, I am under the impression that you're trying to invent concepts that don't exist in object oriented programming and wouldn't work with it. Can you show some more code that shows how you'd want to use those classes **if** what you're trying to do worked?